# Cannot understand React setState signature "setState(updater[, callback])"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know this is probably a JavaScript question rather than a React question, but I cannot understand the above signature of React setState.

What do the square brackets and the comma do inside the function parameter list?

I know how to use it with an updater, but how to use it with callback and again what is this syntax?

Comment: It means that the parameter is optional, either `setState(updater, callback)` or `setState(updater)`

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to update the state, then you can use `setState({ key: 'value' })`

And if you want to perform an action on the updated state just after updation, then you can run `setState({ key: 'value' }, () => callback())` or `setState({ key: 'value' }, callback)`

The callback function should be
`callback() { }` or `callback = () => { }` in react class component

The callback function will run after updating the state.

Note: We use callback because setState use some microseconds to update the state and the next line will be run before updating the state. Then we pass callback which runs after updating the state.

Answer (score 2):

> What do the square brackets and the comma do inside the function parameter list?

That just indicates that passing in the second argument is optional. (This is a very common notation in JavaScript and elsewhere.) You can call `setState` like this:

```
this.setState(newStateOrUpdaterFunction);
```

or like this:

```
this.setState(newStateOrUpdaterFunction, callbackFunction);
```

In the second case, React will call `callbackFunction` when the state update is done. This is useful sometimes because [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

It's relatively rare to want to pass in that second argument. Normally, you just want to re-render after updating state, which React will do automatically by calling your `render` function.

Answer (score 1):

It's an optional parameter.

You may use it the following way :

```
setState( updater, () => { AfterAllSetstateDone_doSomeActionHere; } );
```

The callback is used to inform when all  `setState` calls have been treated.

But it's optional since **you'd rather use the `componentDidUpdate() { someActionHere }` lifecycle hook** in order to deals with fullfilled `setState` calls.